# Add defaultProps on a staless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Maybe this is a silly question, but I don't get why I can't add a default value based on another prop on a stateless component like this one:

```
const Link = ({
  children,
  target,
  rel = target === '_blank' && 'noopener noreferrer',
  href,
  ...attributtes
}) => (
  <a
    {...attributtes}
    target={target}
    rel={rel}
    href={href}
  >
    {children}
  </a>
);

Link.defaultProps = {
  children: <div />,
  target: null,
  rel: null,
};

Link.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  href: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  target: PropTypes.string,
  rel: PropTypes.string,
};

export default Link;
```

Comment: what is the issue, getting any error?

Comment: yes the rel prop is giving null even when I'm passing target='_blank'

Answer (score 2):

Default parameter values aren't used unless they are passed `undefined`. Here's a simplified example of what's going on here.

```
function test(a="foo", b="bar") {
  console.log(a, b);
}

test(undefined, null);
// prints "foo null"
```

Either remove `target` and `rel` from your `defaultProps`, or set them to `undefined`.

```
Link.defaultProps = {
  children: <div />,
  target: undefined,
  rel: undefined,
};
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know about that little quirk. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing `target` to a function that returns the default value:

```
const Link = ({
    children,
    target,
    rel = getRel(target),
    href,
    ...attributtes
}) => (
    <a
        {...attributtes}
        target={target}
        rel={rel}
        href={href}
    >
        {children}
    </a>
);

Link.defaultProps = {
    children: <div />,
    target: null,
    rel: null,
};

Link.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    href: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    target: PropTypes.string,
    rel: PropTypes.string,
};

const getRel = target => target === '_blank' && 'noopener noreferrer';

export default Link;
```

Untested, so not sure if `target` will get passed correctly, but I know that you can use a functions return value as a default param value https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters.